# How to decrease the space between grouped bar-subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a_means, a_CI = (70, 60), (2.7, 1.9)
b_means, b_CI = (85, 83), (2.6, 1.2)
c_means, c_CI = (66, 64), (3.5, 1.8)

ind = np.arange(2)
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
rects1 = ax.bar(ind - 2*width/4, a_means, width/4, yerr=a_CI, label='a')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind - width/4, b_means, width/4, yerr=b_CI, label='b')
rects3 = ax.bar(ind, c_means, width/4, yerr=c_CI, label='c')

ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_ylim([50, 100])
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=3)

plt.show()
```

This is what I get:
[old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIgxn.jpg)

This is what I want to get:
[new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h4Em.jpg)

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'd simplify your code a lot if you'd use Seaborn's sns.barplot with a pandas dataframe.  Seaborn will calculate the confidence intervals and the means for you, display the bars at a nice-looking position and automatically generate a legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `ind = np.arange(2)` to something like:

```
ind = np.arange(2) / 2.5
```

Play with the number, then you can eventually change tick labels if they don't satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Make the bars wider (you can do this easily since you already have a `width` variable for this) and the figure size narrower:

```
width = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```